# Is this a good test to see if a valid enum value is used?

Tags: javascript, enums

Going with what I consider clean, succinct syntax, I've created the following enum in javascript:

```
const DirectionOfTravel = Object.freeze({
    Clockwise: "clockwise",
    CounterClockwise: "counterclockwise",
    Neutral: "neutral"
});
```

It's called like this:

```
const angleDeg = getAngle(pointA, pointB, pointC, DirectionOfTravel.CounterClockwise);
```

And in the getAngle function, because it's critical to returning correct results, I'm calling another function valueInEnum to check that a value has been supplied for direction of travel:

```
const directionIsValid = valueInEnum(direction, DirectionOfTravel);
```

valueInEnum returns true or false:

```
function valueInEnum(value, enumObj) {

    return Object.values(enumObj).includes(value);
}
```

Any better ways of handling this? For example, would it make sense to group Direction of Travel and valueInEnum under a class?

Comment: There's no point in using `!!`, `includes` already returns a boolean.

Comment: Why do you have a class in mind? What would you instantiate it for?

Comment: Perhaps instead of `class` you meant `namespace`?

Comment: @Bergi I removed the !!. I don't need a class and would want to avoid any unnecessary instantiation.